# Django: Problems uploading files with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, upload

I have a problem when I try to upload files with Ajax in Django. I'm using FormData on Javascript. But the problem is in the server side. The files arrive to request.POST as dataURL, it should arrive to request.FILES, but it's empty.

This is my code:

```
var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-theme-edit")),
    url = "/theme/edit/1";

$.ajax({
    "url" : url,
    "method" : "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "data" : form_data,
    "processData" : false
});
```

Comment: Django shouldn't treat your request any different. What does the browser says about your request? check the Chrome developer tools to see how the data was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `contentType` option to `false` to prevent jQuery from attempting to coerce the `FormData` object into a URL-encoded string when it constructs the request payload.  Also, `enctype` is not a valid `$.ajax` option, so you should remove that.